# UIL BufferedInputStream Exception

Tags: android, exception, android-imageview, android-image, universal-image-loader

I'm on 2.3.3 LGP500 using Universal Image Loader library.
I've the following problem: if I somehow quit or simply pause
the activity while downloading the images in a listview, I receive a lot
of exceptions in LogCat; each exception has the same cause:

```
System.err java.io.IOException: BufferedInputStream is close.
```

Ok, how can i handle this? Should I use the listener described in nostra13
documentation?

```
@Override
    public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {
        ...
    }

@Override
    public void onLoadingCancelled(String imageUri, View view) {
        ...
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: this is not happening on N4 with 4.4.

EDIT2: I'm using 1.9.0 UIL. Here's my config:

```
public static void initImageLoader(Context context) {

    DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .resetViewBeforeLoading(true).cacheInMemory(true)
            .cacheOnDisc(true)
            .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY_STRETCHED)
            .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.photo_placeholder)
            .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.photo_placeholder).build();

    ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(
            context).memoryCacheExtraOptions(200, 200)
            .discCacheExtraOptions(200, 200, CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, null)
            .threadPoolSize(5).denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory()
            .memoryCache(new LruMemoryCache(2 * 1024 * 1024))
            .defaultDisplayImageOptions(options).build();

    L.disableLogging();

    ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);

}
```

LogCat:

```
01-11 13:01:21.249: W/System.err(4614): java.io.IOException: BufferedInputStream is closed
01-11 13:01:21.299: W/System.err(4614):     at java.io.BufferedInputStream.streamClosed(BufferedInputStream.java:116)
01-11 13:01:21.299: W/System.err(4614):     at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:274)
01-11 13:01:21.309: W/System.err(4614):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.UnknownLengthHttpInputStream.read(UnknownLengthHttpInputStream.java:40)
01-11 13:01:21.309: W/System.err(4614):     at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fillbuf(BufferedInputStream.java:166)
01-11 13:01:21.309: W/System.err(4614):     at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:324)
01-11 13:01:21.309: W/System.err(4614):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
01-11 13:01:21.309: W/System.err(4614):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:470)
01-11 13:01:21.309: W/System.err(4614):     at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.decode.BaseImageDecoder.defineImageSizeAndRotation(BaseImageDecoder.java:90)
01-11 13:01:21.349: W/System.err(4614):     at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.decode.BaseImageDecoder.decode(BaseImageDecoder.java:70)
01-11 13:01:21.349: W/System.err(4614):     at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.downloadSizedImage(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:342)
01-11 13:01:21.369: W/System.err(4614):     at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.tryCacheImageOnDisc(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:319)
01-11 13:01:21.379: W/System.err(4614):     at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.tryLoadBitmap(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:260)
01-11 13:01:21.379: W/System.err(4614):     at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.run(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:128)
01-11 13:01:21.379: W/System.err(4614):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
01-11 13:01:21.379: W/System.err(4614):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
01-11 13:01:21.389: W/System.err(4614):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

Comment: Which UIL version do you use? Show full error log from LogCat. Show your Config and Display Options.

Comment: Thanks for your time, I've edited my question with additional requested info.